# Why is my CSS being overridden in Vimeo OTT?

Tags: css, vimeo

I'm customizing a Vimeo OTT theme using CSS. I've been able to change fonts, colors, etc. across the theme - except on the video player page. My custom font is being displayed, but the text color is being overridden.

I've tried adding the following and including `!important` to my code, but it's still picking up the original color and overriding my customization.

```
#watch-info > div > div > div.row.margin-vertical-medium > div.column.small-16.medium-8.large-10 > div.contain.margin-top-large.column.small-16 > h1 { 
color: #000000 !important;
}

.site-font-primary-color, .site-font-primary-color strong {
    color: #000000 !important;
}
```

After adding this code in, I'm still seeing the following when I inspect the element I'm trying to change:

```
.site-font-primary-color, .site-font-primary-color strong {
    color: #ffffff !important;
}
```

Is there something that I am missing? Is there a reason why Vimeo is overriding this?

Answer (score -1):

The use of the `important` tag can be confusing.

Let's say you have two classes `.a` and `.b`, both classes set the `color` property using the `!important` flag. In your css `.b` is defined **after** `.a`.

```
.a{
  color: black !important;
}

.b{
  color: red !important;
}
```

There is an element in your HTML `<div class="a b"></div>`. Your `<div>` will always have the `color` property of class `.b`. Not because `b` is the last class you assigned to the div, but because the class `.b` is defined **after** class `.a` in your css file.
So it does not work as you would expected. The order of the element's classes are **irrelevant**, the order of the definitions of your classes in your css files **matter**.

So try to *append* your overwrite-class at the end of the CSS file.

Have a look at my codepen. There you can test and switch the classes `a` and `b`, for instance from `class="a b"` to `class="b a"` or change the order of the class definitions.

[CSS important](https://codepen.io/michaelkonstreu/pen/NWNZGej)

Comment: Hmmm. I see what you mean here, but I actually adding both of those elements as different ways to target the element - both aren't working, even if added to the bottom of my CSS customizations. 

It seems to me like there is something similar to what you've pointed out being overriding my customization by Vimeo that I don't have access to editing?

Comment: Did you try to add some other properties in your class for testing, for instance ````.site-font-primary-color, .site-font-primary-color strong {color: #000000 !important; text-transform: uppercase;}````. Then you could use the developer tools and check if the added property is added in the element, too. Maybe there is another css line which overrides it.